# Cloud Foundry alternative for 'docker run --add-host'

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcfdev

If I want to add an entry in the /etc/hosts file of a container, in Docker, I can use following command:

```
docker run --add-host foo:10.0.0.3 myimage
```

If I want to do the same in Pivotal Cloud Foundry application, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a buildpack to deploy your application then you cannot.  Applications deployed via buildpack run as the `vcap` user and do *not* have root access, so you cannot edit `/etc/hosts`.

If you're using Docker to deploy your application on CloudFoundry, you could modify the `/etc/hosts` file in your image and that would persist through to your application when it runs on CF.  That said, I don't know of any way to do this dynamically as you run the image like the command you referenced above.

Comment: I know this answer's ancient, but can you actually do this? Reading through other answers (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/40721996/3166095), it doesn't appear that `/etc/hosts` modifications are persisted into the image