# question for docker build --add-host command

Tags: docker

I am an infra admin for providing docker images to developers.

I created "A" images and then tell docker run command is

```
docker run --add-host=a-lic:10.0.0.1 --add-host=b-lic:10.0.0.2 A
```

every developers request to me, please remove --add-host option because it is long.
So I want to edit /etc/hosts file when docker build if possible.

I find out `docker build --add-host` option newly create from 17.04
but it does not work as my expected.

someone said --add-host option is for only during building image
and another said --add-host option will work as below (my thoughts).

```
docker build --add-host=a-lic:10.0.0.1 -t A .
docker run -it A
```

And docker's documentation is not sufficient for this.

```
$ docker build --help
Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile

Options:
      --add-host list           Add a custom host-to-IP mapping (host:ip)
```

What is the correct??

Answer (score 6):

It's by design (see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34078#issuecomment-314798584 / https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/30383#issuecomment-314797629); the `--add-host` feature during build is designed to allow overriding a host during build, but *not* to persist that configuration in the image.

If it *would* persist in the image;

- the image would not be portable (i.e., only work in your specific environment)
- images would be able to spoof DNS (what if an image contained `google.com 123.123.123.123` ?)

The person *running* an image should remain in control over overriding hosts, not the image author; it's a runtime configuration.

Possible solutions For your situation;

- Run an internal DNS; you can set the default DNS server to use in the daemon; that way every container started will automatically use the configured DNS by default
- Use docker compose and provide a `docker-compose.yml` to your developers. The docker compose file allows you to specify all the options that should be used when starting a container, so developers could just `docker compose up` to start the container with all the options they need to set.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach that would work here, if a bit ugly. This is for Windows, you can easily do the same on Linux.

In your `docker run` pass in an environment variable e.g.

```
docker run --env HOST_IP_ADDRESS=a-lic:10.0.0.1
```

Then at the end of your Dockerfile, you have a batch file or script in the CMD that runs your application e.g

```
CMD [ "app-start.bat" ]
```

Add the following line to `app-start.bat`:

```
echo %HOST_IP_ADDRESS% >> c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

You can add multiple of these if required.