# Shinyproxy - How to pass Hosts to docker image

Tags: r, docker, shinyproxy

How can I pass the hosts saved in `/etc/hosts` into the docker image while building it.

I want to do this automatically, so that this snippet works on all server environments.

I tried this in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY /etc/hosts /etc/hosts
```

But obviously that didnt work with the following error:

> COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder736360024/etc/hosts: no such file or
>   directory

---

I also tried to move the `hosts` (`cp /etc/hosts /app/dir`) first in my app-folder and then copying only with in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY hosts /etc/hosts
```

That didn't throw an error, but looking in a docker container, the container hosts are not the same as the hosting machine.

---

I also tried to build the image with the additional `--add-host` parameter, but that also did not work.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: which os you are on? try to use `--network=host` if its linux?

Comment: Yes it's Linux.. You mean in the build command?

Comment: AFAIK /etc/hosts is belongs to docker its not easy to update. u defined the network mode when u running the container, with host mode u will use the host machine network https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/ but it has some limitation. Check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302867/how-to-update-etc-hosts-file-in-docker-image-during-docker-build

Comment: Why can’t you run a DNS service?  (Something like Route 53 in an AWS environment; or Consul; or BIND; or ....)  Manually maintaining `/etc/hosts` and keeping it in sync in multiple places is a huge hassle.