# After Docker Commit my changes are not saving to Image

Tags: docker

My `Docker Version - 19.03.8, build afacb8b`

I have pulled the `ubuntu:18.04` from `DockerHub`. Then followed the below steps to add two new lines into `/etc/hosts` file of my docker image.

```
docker images
docker run --name ubuntu-18-1 -idt 8b353a2e5d1b /bin/bash
docker ps
# Executed the Container
docker exec -it 985ae774a352 /bin/bash
root@985ae774a352:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      985ae774a352
```

After adding the following two new lines (`56.57.58.59 example1.com` & `56.57.58.60 example2.com`) into `/etc/hosts` file of my container, Then after i have saved, exited and then finally i have committed my container.

```
docker commit 985ae774a352 ubuntu-18-2
# Even after commit i can able to view the changes i made.
docker exec 985ae774a352 cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      985ae774a352
56.57.58.59 example1.com
56.57.58.60 example2.com

# Stopped & Removed the Container
docker container stop 985ae774a352
docker container rm 985ae774a352

# Launched the Container with udpated Image:-
docker run --name ubuntu-18-2 -idt 0ebc2d94a384 /bin/bash
docker ps
docker exec a8c1fa1dd65f cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      a8c1fa1dd65f
```

So in new image i can't see my changes that i made in `/etc/hosts` file. Please correct me if something wrong in above followed steps.

Comment: You almost never want to use `docker commit`; building an image out of a Dockerfile using `docker build` is much better practice, and you'll have written down how to rebuild the image when there's a critical security issue in the base image in a year that you must fix.  Similarly, setting up a DNS system (like BIND, DNSMasq, or a service-discovery system like Consul) will be more maintainable than trying to replicate `/etc/hosts` files in multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the /etc/hosts is regenerated every time the `docker run` is executed.

In order to add new hosts, you can use the option `--add-host`. e.g.

```
docker run \
    --name ubuntu-18-1 \
    --add-host example1.com:56.57.58.59 \
    --add-host example2.com:56.57.58.60 \
    -idt ubuntu:18.04 \
    /bin/bash
```

More info can be found in the section [Managing /etc/hosts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts) of the docker documentation.

Comment: Thanks Adii & Stefano for quick support. i have changed the logic and it works now. Thanks

Comment: just another note, you can also use the tag instead of the id in the docker run. e.g. `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04 bash` is the equivalent of `docker run -it --rm 8b353a2e5d1b bash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not commit changes to `/etc/hosts`, as docker maintain `/etc/hosts` when you start the container, you might notice one thing whenever you start the container, docker generate `/etc/host`

for example

```
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  c71f7cfa8140
```

you can look at bottom of `/etc/hosts`, you can see the last entry or somewhere in the file you will see running container id, you can cross-check with

```
docker ps
```

so you should change your logic something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40721996/3288890) or better to use [--add-host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/network-settings)