# Docker container has access to internet but not the local network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a windows docker container running on win server 2016

The the site running in the container is accessible from other nodes on the network.

The container has access to the internet (it can access 3rd party nodes external to the network), but it is unable to connect to other nodes in the network.

When an app running in the container tries to access a service on another machine in the network (machine_name) it gets the following error:

`The remote name could not be resolved: machine_name`

When the app tries to connect to a database on the network:

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection`

So it looks like the container does not have access or cannot find the machines on intranet

I ran  `docker exec -ti e87633560c6c ipconfig /all`   and got the following:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : gmsa_acct
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Container NIC 0b35fe9f):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-30-F4-1D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7939:903e:141f:5c98%24(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.223.136(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.208.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.208.1
                                       10.xxx
                                       10.xxx
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

I ran this command in the machine that the container is running on

```
docker exec e87633560c6c nltest /sc_verify:mydomain.com
Flags: b0 HAS_IP  HAS_TIMESERV
Trusted DC Name \\D1dns01.mydomain.com
Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
Trust Verification Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
The command completed successfully
```

The strange thing is that the same container ran on another host without any issues. We are now trying to run it on a new host and are getting the above issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: I am able to connect via the IP address and not the machine name.
How can I connect via the machine name?

Comment: Can you please tell me your `docker for windows` version?

Comment: Docker version 19.03.12, build 4306744

Comment: You probably need to setup a Docker DNS. c.f. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/
There is a stackoverflow answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302867/how-to-update-etc-hosts-file-in-docker-image-during-docker-build
You will need to define your own "/etc/hosts" file with the hostname and its ipaddr resolution

Answer (score 2):

use the following command

```
docker run -d --network host -p 8080:80 <container_name>
```

The --network host command makes it accessible to machines on the same network.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Enable forwarding from Docker containers to the outside world

Configure the Linux kernel to allow IP forwarding.

a. **sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1**

Change the policy for the iptables FORWARD policy from DROP to ACCEPT.

b. **sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT**

These settings do not persist across a reboot, so you may need to add them to a start-up script.

These commands are to be run on host machine

Answer (score 0):

When Docker create a network for its running container, as default it create a NATed network of type [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-the-default-bridge-network). You can fine more detail about your container's network with the command `docker network ls`, the results it's like these:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
17e324f45964        bridge              bridge              local
6ed54d316334        host                host                local
7092879f2cc8        none                null                local
```

You can try with "host" network configuration:

> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s
> network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container
> shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not
> get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container
> which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s
> application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

[Use host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Comment: I do have neither host nor bridge. I see only nat and none. What am I missing please?

Comment: also host networking is not available on windows it seems

Comment: The problem here is windows. Docker on Windows runs on an virtual machine! (unless you use wsl2)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your DNS settings are not working.  It looks like a lot of reports are out there of similar issues with Docker on Windows (see [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3810)).   But here are a few options to try:

- Step up to latest docker version (if you're not there already)
- Resetting to factory settings (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#reset))
- Assigning a static DNS server through your daemon.json file, for example:

`"dns" : ["8.8.8.8"]`

Comment: I agree issue is DNS, but I don't think this solution will work for local network

Answer (score 0):

Something silly that happened to me and might help others:
The container doesn't know the domain of the network, so try adding the domain at the end of the hostname.

In my case I had a Oracle host named `ora_apl`, had to call it as `ora_apl.domain.com`.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in @a_manfrinati answer, the default network `brige` is used by a new container. In your case it looks both nodes are not running on same network.

Try creating a network first and then adding nodes later to it:

```
$ docker network create my_new_network
$ docker container run -d --name node1 --network my_new_network node1
$ docker container run -d --name node2 --network my_new_network node2
```

Also note that the DNS name will be same as the container name.