# Max retries exceeded with url in Requests Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request, httpurlconnection

i try to send request to this URL : [Site URL](http://www.dsit.org.ir/?cmd=page&Cid=92&title=Kontakt&lang=fa)

And do a simple page reading with the following code :

```
import requests
url_1 = 'http://www.dsit.org.ir/?cmd=page&Cid=92&title=Kontakt&lang=fa'
print(requests.get(url_1).text)
```

But i get this Error :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.srgfesrsergserg.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000008EC69AAA90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

This site is very basic and has **no special security** measures. Also, I only requested it once

Everything is fine and I open this page very easily with ***Request-html*** but I do not know what the problem is here !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add headers.

Disguise the browser.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}

url_1 = 'http://www.dsit.org.ir/?cmd=page&Cid=92&title=Kontakt&lang=fa'

print(requests.get(url=url_1, headers=headers).text)
```

Comment: WOOOW this is awesome 
its work nice, bro thank you,Can you tell what browser and system it is for?

Comment: `F12 Network` -> F5 -> `Request Headers` Click any one afterwards, there is user-agent

Comment: No problem. I enjoyed helping you.

Comment: yes i find it, But I want to know what browser this header is ?

Comment: Everyone is different, I get it directly from my browser.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you send too many requests to the public IP address of `https://www.dsit.org.ir`. It as you can see caused due to some reason which does not allow/block access to the public IP address mapping with `https://www.dsit.org.ir`. One better solution is the following python script which calculates the public IP address of any domain and creates that mapping to the /etc/hosts file.

```
import re
import socket
import subprocess
from typing import Tuple

ENDPOINT = 'https://anydomainname.example.com/'
ENDPOINT = 'https://www.dsit.org.ir/'

def get_public_ip() -> Tuple[str, str, str]:
    """
    Command to get public_ip address of host machine and endpoint domain
    Returns
    -------
    my_public_ip : str
        Ip address string of host machine.
    end_point_ip_address : str
        Ip address of endpoint domain host.
    end_point_domain : str
        domain name of endpoint.

    """
    # bash_command = """host myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | \
    #     grep "myip.opendns.com has" | awk '{print $4}'"""
    # bash_command = """curl ifconfig.co"""
    # bash_command = """curl ifconfig.me"""
    bash_command = """ curl icanhazip.com"""
    my_public_ip = subprocess.getoutput(bash_command)
    my_public_ip = re.compile("[0-9.]{4,}").findall(my_public_ip)[0]
    end_point_domain = (
        ENDPOINT.replace("https://", "")
        .replace("http://", "")
        .replace("/", "")
    )
    end_point_ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(end_point_domain)
    return my_public_ip, end_point_ip_address, end_point_domain


def set_etc_host(ip_address: str, domain: str) -> str:
    """
    A function to write mapping of ip_address and domain name in /etc/hosts.
    Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302867/how-to-update-etc-hosts-file-in-docker-image-during-docker-build

    Parameters
    ----------
    ip_address : str
        IP address of the domain.
    domain : str
        domain name of endpoint.

    Returns
    -------
    str
        Message to identify success or failure of the operation.

    """
    bash_command = """echo "{}    {}" >> /etc/hosts""".format(ip_address, domain)
    output = subprocess.getoutput(bash_command)
    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_public_ip, end_point_ip_address, end_point_domain = get_public_ip()
    output = set_etc_host(ip_address=end_point_ip_address, domain=end_point_domain)
    print("My public IP address:", my_public_ip)
    print("ENDPOINT public IP address:", end_point_ip_address)
    print("ENDPOINT Domain Name:", end_point_domain )
    print("Command output:", output)
```

You can call the above script before running your desired function :)