# How to access domain'd resource running from a port the host during a docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hosts, docker-build

I need to access a domain name during my docker build, say **example.com**, which is currently running on my host machine (Mac), through the hosts file:

```
[/etc/hosts]

127.0.0.1      example.com
```

and exposed on port 8888. If I try to use this ip in the docker build process, it fails to establish the connection:

```
docker build  --add-host=example.com:127.0.0.1 .
```

Using my host's local ip address using `ipconfig getifaddr en0` also fails:

```
docker build  --add-host=example.com:$(ipconfig getifaddr en0) .
```

Presumably this is because my host system is not allowing incoming connections on this port; I am also fine with this, ideally I would not need to open the port up externally to make this work.
Indeed I can't even access the resource in the host terminal with this ip, for example with `curl $(ipconfig getifaddr en0):8888` fails. However `ping $(ipconfig getifaddr en0)` does work, verifying the ip address is correct.

Since Docker 20.10, the "host-gateway" token was added to the cli. This means you can now access the host using `host.docker.internal` (yes, even on linux) with the command

```
docker build --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway .
```

However I need to access the host by resolving the local domain `example.com` and the following does not work for me:

```
docker build --add-host=example.com:host-gateway .
```

During the build process we can get the ip address of the host by resolving `host.docker.internal` however updating the `/etc/hosts` file in the image,  does not work as detailed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302867/how-to-update-etc-hosts-file-in-docker-image-during-docker-build#:%7E:text=reference/builder/%23entrypoint-,Share,-Edit). The accepted solution is to use `--add-host` to the `docker build ...` command that kicks off the build process.

Before the build process however, when we are able to configure `example.com` to point to an ip address with `docker build --add-host`, I don't know how to   see where `docker.host.internal` would point to.

Currently, the solution I have is to run the `docker build` with the directive

```
RUN apt-get -y install iputils-ping && ping host.docker.internal
```

Then I quit the build, copy the ip address output from the directive (192.168.65.2) and into the command

```
docker build --add-host=example.com:192.168.65.2 .
```

Now, this does work, but it's a brittle, cumbersome and fairly desperate hack. What would be the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: What do you need to call out to during the build?  Can you pass the host name as a Dockerfile `ARG`, and use `--build-arg whatever-host=host.docker.internal` if the external dependency happens to be running on the same machine?  (I would avoid trying to set up `/etc/hosts` in favor of making the actual destination host name configurable.)

Comment: @DavidMaze the resource is a package repository and is not only hard-coded in the configuration files for the install, but also hard-coded in the trees of dependency files pulled down through the install process.

Comment: @DavidMaze the resource is **currently** running on the same machine, but I want the ability to move it elsewhere without having to change the process. It allows me to have this process run as an integration / unit test.

Comment: If Docker weren't involved, how would you move it?  Editing `/etc/hosts` on every system that could run this build seems unreliable; maybe you'd use sed(1) to change those files with the build configuration?

Comment: Production will just use DNS. Test environment will use /etc/hosts.